# Users granted entry through flask_login

Tags: authentication, flask-login, flask-session

I have a problem with my website which is built using python, flask, gunicorn + supervisorctl, nginx stack.

The problem is: if I am logged on as a user (say admin for e.g.) after restarting my website through "sudo supervisorctl reload' after making some updates to it, any user who attempts to login afterwards becomes logged in as admin even if they enter a random username and password combination. Obviously this is very alarming.

I'm currently using the flask_login plugin to handle the login but I suspect is something to do with flask sessions and how it interacts.

My login code is below

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, current_app, session
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required

@bp.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.user'))
    form=LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username = form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('main.user')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('auth/login.html', title=_('登录'), form=form)
```

I also use flask session to identify the current language and mange translations

in main routing:

```
@bp.before_app_request  ####Michael: becareful of these
def before_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        current_user.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()


@bp.context_processor
def inject_conf_var():
    return dict(CURRENT_LANGUAGE=session.get('language', 
request.accept_languages.best_match(current_app.config['LANGUAGES'])))
```

and in my **init**

```
@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    # if the user has set up the language manually it will be stored in the session,
    # so we use the locale from the user settings
    try:
        language = session['language']
        print(session['language'])
    except KeyError:
        language = None
    if language is not None:
        return language
    return 
request.accept_languages.best_match(current_app.config['LANGUAGES'])
```

I'm not really sure where to start identifying what the problem is, its a bit beyond me at the moment. Closest thing i saw was this:

[Users appear to be logged in as another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668355/users-appear-to-be-logged-in-as-another-user)

but the same thing seems to happen across computers in my case so not really a VPN issue, I'm not sure if the same solution would work.

Grateful for any help!